# LTC4417 power path converter not working

Tags: power-supply, batteries, switching, mosfet-driver

I am fairly new to PCB design and I am having trouble understanding why my PCB is not working. I am using a [LTC4417](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/4417f.pdf) power path converter and a [IRF7324](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf7324.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355f5e10a1b47) power MOSFET to turn on an embedded system with a pair of 14.4 V batteries. I have one internal battery and one swappable battery in my system.

My system has an ON button (JP5 connection) that when shorted routes >1 V to the LTC4417 ENABLE pin that should then result in V1 (on the LTC4417) being routed to Vout (on the LTC4417) and the MOSFET opening, thus allowing BINT_OUT to flow to V_toboard.

Problems:
The gate drivers VS1 and G1 show the same voltage so the MOSFET is not opening. I believe G1 should be pulled low causing the MOSFET to open.

I have shown three pictures below. The first is the schematic of the power controller section of my board.

The second picture shows all the voltage readings on each of the LTC4417 pins when the EN pin is low.

The third picture shows all of the voltage readings on each pin of the LTC4417 when the EN pin is high. In this scenario, V_toboard should be the same as B_int. Note: VALID1 connected to a pullup resistor and the 16.3 V reads a value of 0.4 V but should read 0 V when the voltage into V1 is valid.

Can you help me solve why the Vtoboard does not match Bint_out?

[image: This is the schematic of the power converter section of my board]

[image: Voltages on each pin of LTC4417 when EN pin is low]

[image: Voltages on each pin of LTC4417 when EN pin is high]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please rotate your bottom diagrams so they are readable. If over sized the software will insert horizontal or vertical elevators bars as required.

Comment: Jordan did you compare your design with the Demo board?  What are the differences?  power sources and battery differences?

Comment: V_valid only requires UV and OV to be both < 1V. and G1 has to go low for the external PFETs to switch V_toboard to B_int_out

Comment: Are you using the SSOP package or the QFN package?

Comment: Also, why are you shorting CAS to ground?

Comment: @Dan Laks, I am using the SSOP package. The data sheet does specify to leave CAS open when not grounded. Thanks for the find, but it also says that CAS is pulled low when any input supply is within the OV/UV window for at least 256ms and both SHDN and EN are above 1V. Since those conditions are met, shouldn't CAS be low anyway and me connecting it to and not affect the chip

Comment: @Tony Stewart, I have not compared my design with the Demo board and am unsure which demo board you are referring to. Although I have compared it to schematics in the data sheet and the main difference in the CAS pin as Dan mentioned.

Comment: @Tony Stewart, I believe V_valid1 should pull to 0 when OV1 <1V and when UV1 > 1V. This confirms that V1 is in valid range and should be routed to V_out and G1 should pull low to turn the mosfet on. The voltages at OV1 and UV1 show that V1 is valid, but VALID1 does not confirm this and the V_toboard still doesn't match B_intout. G1 is not pulling low as G1 and VS1 have the same voltage.

Comment: is it unstable? didi you scope everything?  Did you answer my question comparing with Demo board?

Comment: @Tony Stewart, I have not scoped everything as I currently do not have access to an oscilloscope. I have not compared my design with the Demo board and am unsure which demo board you are referring to.

Comment: You can buy a demo board from Digikey. It has all the details in layout, setup.  Compare with yours.  You may have done something different.